# shell script : comma in the beginning instead of end

Tags: shell, unix

This is a part of my shell script.

```
for line in `cat $1`
do
        startNum=`echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`
        endNum=`echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $2}'`
        operator=`echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $3}'`
        termPrefix=`echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $4}'`

        if [[ "$endNum" == 81* ]] || [[ "$endNum" == 33* ]] || [[ "$endNum" == 55* ]]
        then
                areaCode="${endNum:0:2}"
                series="${endNum:2:4}"
                startCLI="${startNum:6:4}"
                endCLI="${endNum:6:4}"
        else
                areaCode="${endNum:0:3}"
                series="${endNum:3:3}"
                startCLI="${startNum:6:4}"
                endCLI="${endNum:6:4}"
        fi

echo "Add,${areaCode},${series},${startCLI},${endCLI},${termPrefix},"
#>> ${File}

done
```

input is csv contains below many rows :

```
5557017101,5557017101,102,1694
5515585614,5515585614,102,084
```

Output od shell script :

```
,dd,55,5701,7101,7101,1694
,dd,55,1558,5614,5614,0848
```

Not sure why comma is coming in startign of output, instead as per shell script it should come in the end.

please help

Comment: I suppose your input `csv` contains DOS CRLF endings `\r\n`. Could you run `dos2unix <input-csv>` before parsing the file?

Comment: In addition to trailing `\r`, your script is very inefficient as you are calling `awk` multiple times for each line. Whole script can be written using a single `awk`.

Comment: when i did set list on vi editor over file, it show me $ in the end of every line. Then i replaced $ with comma (,). It worked. Not sure why there is $ which is visible after i did set list

Comment: FYI, dos2unix did not work. Was getting the same output.

Comment: @VJS; Show output of `cat -A file.csv`

Comment: Don't parse lines like this.  Try `while IFS=, read startNum endNum operator termPrefix _ ; do ... ; done < $1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested `awk` command that should replace all of your shell+awk code. This `awk` also takes care of trailing `\r`:

```
awk -v RS=$'\r' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF>3{
   startNum=$1; endNum=$2; termPrefix=$4; 
   if (endNum ~ /^(81|33|55)/) {
      areaCode=substr(endNum,1,2); series=substr(endNum,3,4)
   }
   else {
      areaCode=substr(endNum,1,3); series=substr(endNum,4,3)
   } 
   startCLI=substr(startNum,7,4); endCLI=substr(endNum,7,4);
   print "Add", areaCode, series, startCLI, endCLI, termPrefix
}' file

Add,55,5701,7101,7101,1694
Add,55,1558,8561,5614,084
```